# PreferenceFragmentCompat won't load in AppCompatPreferenceActivity - Trying to instantiate a class that is not a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-preferences

I'm trying to use PreferenceFragmentCompat from the v7 support library.  When I try to add it, it always returns the following exception

```
Process: com.sample.preferencetest, PID: 14444
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sample.preferencetest/com.sample.preferencetest.SettingsActivity}: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.sample.preferencetest.SettingsActivity$EmptyFragment that is not a Fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3155)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3263)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1687)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6897)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

When I try to use a PreferenceFragment with this, everything works fine.  It's only when I try to use the PreferenceFragmentCompat that it fails

The reason I want to use this, is because the onAttach(Activity) method is now deprecated, and earlier devices weren't attaching my interface.

This is the class

```
package com.sample.preferencetest;

import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;  I toggle this to try regular preference fragments.
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;
import java.util.List;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
    }

    protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
        return true;
    }

    public static class EmptyFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        public EmptyFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {
        }
    }
}
```

Headers XML

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <header
    android:fragment="com.sample.preferencetest.SettingsActivity$EmptyFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/pref_header_general" />
</preference-headers>
```

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.preferencetest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

How am I supposed to use the PreferenceFragmentCompat, if not this way?

Comment: `onAttach(Activity activity)` is deprecated. Use instead `onAttach(Context context)`. Works in both cases

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem occurs, because framework fragments and support fragments are not compatible. If you're using the `AppCompatPreferenceActivity` from the samples of the support library, you're using a normal `PreferenceActivity` with toolbar support. Support fragments are not supported there. That's why `PreferenceFragment` works fine and `PreferenceFragmentCompat` doesn't.

If you're only concerned about `onAttach(Activity)` being deprecated, don't be. The default implementation of `onAttach(Context)` just calls through to it when attached to an activtiy. Therefore it's safe to only implement `onAttach(Activity)` to be compatible with all current versions of Android.

Comment: How load headers `onBuildHeaders` with PreferenceFragmentCompat and AppCompatPreferenceActivity ?

Comment: @Andreyua If it's the example `AppCompatPreferenceActivity`, you can't.

Comment: without `AppCompatPreferenceActivity`, but with `PreferenceFragmentCompat` ?

Comment: @Andreyua `onBuildHeaders()` was introduced with Honeycomb for `PreferenceFragment` only. I don't know about a port for the support library. Read up on https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#BackCompatHeaders

Comment: But `PreferenceFragment` not support material theme for API Level < 21 . Only  `PreferenceFragmentCompat` - but without `onBuildHeaders` for supporting tablets. 
And - what the point?

Comment: @Andreyua this is not realy the point of this question, but a good one by itself. You should ask a new one and maybe leave the link here. I'd be interested in an answer to this as well.

Answer (score -1):

Add compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:24.1.1' to gradle and use

```
android.support.v14.preference.PreferenceFragment
```

instead of

```
android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.
```

This solved the problem for me.